# Ajax recebendo array que não deveria

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou montando um formulário de cadastro em popup, então precisei usar Ajax na autenticação. Acontece que quando digito um e-mail já cadastrado ele me mostra a mensagem corretamente (E-mail já registrado!), mas quando coloco um e-mail não cadastrado, ele primeiro me mostra  a mensagem de (E-mail já registrado!) e depois me mostra a mensagem de (Cadastrado com sucesso!).

```
$("#btn-cadastro").click(function(){

var data = $("#myRegister").serialize();

$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url  : 'conexao/cadastro.php',
data : data,
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function()
{   
    $("#btn-cadastro").html('Validando ...');
},
success :  function(response){                      
    if(response.erro == "0"){   
        $("#pass-info3").css('display', 'none')
        $("#btn-cadastro").html('Entrar');
        $("#btn-cadastro").prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
        $("#pass-info3").removeClass( "weakpass" )
        $("#pass-info3").addClass( "goodpass" )
        $("#pass-info3").css('display', 'block')
        $("#pass-info3").html(response.mensagem);
        }, 4101);
        setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
        }, 6101);
    }else{
        if(response.erro == "1"){   
            $("#pass-info3").css('display', 'none')
            $("#pass-info3").removeClass( "goodpass" )
            $("#pass-info3").addClass( "weakpass" )
            $("#btn-cadastro").prop('disabled', true);
            setTimeout(function () {
            $("#btn-cadastro").html('Entrar');
            $("#btn-cadastro").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#pass-info3").css('display', 'block')
            $("#pass-info3").html('<strong>Erro! </strong>' + response.mensagem);
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
});
});
```

E o php que faz o cadastro é esse:

```
// Conexao com o Banco de Dados
require_once("conexao.php");

// Recebe os dados de cadastro
$nome       = (isset($_POST['nome'])) ? $_POST['nome'] : null;
$email      = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$telefone   = (isset($_POST['telefone'])) ? $_POST['telefone'] : null;
$senha      = (isset($_POST['senha'])) ? $_POST['senha'] : null;
$rsenha     = (isset($_POST['rsenha'])) ? $_POST['rsenha'] : null;

// Criptografa senha
$custo     = '08';
$salt      = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
$hash = crypt($senha, '$2a$' . $custo . '$' . $salt . '$');

if (empty($nome) || empty($email) || empty($telefone) || empty($senha) || empty($rsenha)):
    $retorno  = array('erro' => '1', 'mensagem' => 'Preencha todos os campos!');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
else:

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email';
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    $resposta1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (is_array($resposta1)):
        $retorno  = array('erro' => '1', 'mensagem' => 'E-mail ja registrado!');
        echo json_encode($retorno);
    else:
        $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, email, telefone, senha) VALUES(:nome, :email, :telefone, :hash)';
        $stmt2 = $conexao->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':hash', $hash);
        $resposta2 = $stmt2->execute();

        if( ! $resposta2 ):
            $retorno  = array('erro' => '1', 'mensagem' => 'Não foi possivel completar o cadastro!');
            echo json_encode($retorno);
        else:
            $retorno  = array('erro' => '0', 'mensagem' => 'Cadastrado com sucesso!');
            echo json_encode($retorno);
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
```

Tenho outro igual só que com apenas 1 query para Login, e funciona normalmente. Imagino que deva ser algo que passou despercebido ou que eu n saiba mesmo, então agradeceria se me ajudassem!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` retorna uma array vazia quando o registro não existe.

Tente alterar a seguinte linha:

```
if (is_array($resposta1)):
```

Para

```
if (is_array($resposta1) && count($resposta1) > 0):
```

Comment: Amigo, deu a mesma coisa. Fiz um teste aqui agora dessa query sem PDO, no jeito antigo com (mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0), ele faz a mesma coisa. E outra coisa, tem if: else: endif; se aparece que o email ja esta registrado, é porque ele parou no If correto ? Por que entao ele estaria continuando para o else , ele ta fazendo tudo, tanto o if quanto o else.

Comment: Tem razão, então pelo que descreveu parece estar chamando a página duas vezes. Tente adicionar uma verificação para validar se ocorreu um post na página. `if (!empty($_POST))`. Não tenho certeza de que o empty irá funcionar para campos nulos. Então pode estar passando na validação de empty caso esteja caindo no else da sua condição ternária.

Comment: Amigo, aparentemente o problema não estava no PHP, mas sim no JS, como pode ver, eu coloquei o requisição Ajax dentro da minha validação, de forma que se tudo estivesse correto, ele executaria a requisição Ajax. Fiz um teste coloquei que se tudo estivesse certo, uma variável errosCadastro receberia "0", e fora da validação dos inputs, coloquei a condição if(errosCadastro == "0"), coloquei o Ajax dentro, e funcionou, agora fiquei sem intender o motivo de não funcionar antes. Vou continuar procurando, pois algo nos meus métodos esta errado. Agradeço a ajuda que me deu. Vlw